# Server Error in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

My ASP.NET application runs perfectly on the Development server but when I try to deploy it to the local IIS server or a free hosting provider server, it turns with an unhandled exception in both cases an the error in the latter case being:

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

I've spent days trying to sort out this problem but every where it asks for checking the remote login connections.In spite of all that, the error turns out again and again. Please help.

Comment: Verify that connection string is correct. You probably have development environment connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article may help:

[How to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)

Answer (score 0):

can you telnet to post 1433 on the sql server box?

try this in the command line from your local iis box:

```
telnet servername 1433
```

If it doesn't connect through the command line, then you will need to open security ports to the sql box.

If it connects fine, then you might want to check your connection string settings.
Can you provide your web.config if this is the case.